# How do I provide STDIN data to a J script run via jconsole.exe?

Tags: j

I want to run a J script, providing STDIN, and receive the output of the script with STDOUT.

I feel like I'm missing something blindingly obvious, but the [help pages on using jconsole.exe](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/user/cmdline.htm) are . . . terse.

My naive thought was that I could run the following in the cmd.exe shell to provide STDIN:

```
jconsole.exe script.ijs inputstring
```

While that works without the attempted STDIN:

```
C:\..\bin>jconsole.exe "C:\path\no-input-script.ijs"
success
C:\..\bin>
```

The `no-input-script.ijs` file is the following:

```
stdout 'success'
exit ''
```

I have the following `script-with-input.ijs` file:

```
input =: stdin ''
stdout 'input was ' , input
exit ''
```

When I run the following, the system hangs:

```
C:\..\bin>jconsole.exe "C:\path\script-with-input.ijs" xyz
```

When I then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the script exits and I am left with the following:

```
C:\..\bin>jconsole.exe "C:\path\script-with-input.ijs" xyz
input was
C:\..\bin>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`stdin` reads input from STDIN until EOF (usually in *nix ^D). So your 'script-with-input.ijs' waits for user input or a pipe.

```
c:>jconsole.exe "script-with-input.ijs" hello
this is user input
^D
input was this is user input
```

What you, instead, are trying to do is read the arguments of the command. Those are stored in ARGV:

```
NB. script-with-input.ijs
input =: ARGV
echo input
exit''
```

Then:

```
c:>jconsole.exe "script-with-input.ijs" hello
┌────────────┬─────────────────────┬─────┐
│jconsole.exe│script-with-input.ijs│hello│
└────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Would you mind expanding your answer with an example of piping in "hello" to my script-with-input.ijs? If it is piped in, will my script behave as expected?

Comment: I can't verify this on windows but the following should work: 1. redirect input `jconsole script.ijs < input.txt` 2. pipe commands `echo "hello" | jsconsole script.ijs` 3. pipe text file `type input.txt | jsconsole script.ijs`.